# i get null value while catching following attribute accept image. Why?

Tags: java, image, jsp, servlets, upload

hello everyone i get null value while fetching the value of name, lastname etc..
but my image upload going well and good as well as the image is moved or stored to desired location....please help this is my code

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)
    {
        fileItem = initRequest(req);

```
    name=req.getParameter("name");
    middlename=req.getParameter("middlename");
    lastname=req.getParameter("lastname");
    age=21;
    //age=Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("age"));
    gender=req.getParameter("gender");
    email=req.getParameter("email");
    mobno=req.getParameter("mobno");
    religion=req.getParameter("religion");
    nationality=req.getParameter("nationality");
    username=req.getParameter("username");
    password=req.getParameter("password");
    rstatus=req.getParameter("rstatus");
    System.out.println(req.getParameter("rstatus"));
    File file = uploadFile(fileItem,"G://Friendbook//pictures");

    try 
    {
        ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into mem_info values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1,name);
        ps.setString(2, middlename);
        ps.setString(3, lastname);
        ps.setInt(4,age);
        ps.setString(5, gender);
        ps.setString(6, email);
        ps.setString(7, mobno);
        ps.setString(8, religion);
        ps.setString(9, nationality);
        ps.setString(10, username);
        ps.setString(11, password);
        ps.setString(12, rstatus);
        ps.setString(13,file.getName());

        System.out.println("file name "+file.getName());
        int result=ps.executeUpdate();

        if (result > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Ragistration successfull");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Ragistration failed");
        }
    }

    catch(Exception e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: If your .getParameter returns null, then that parameter is not there. Have you tried putting a breakpoint and exploring the request object in your IDE? Also, it's spelled "rEgistration".

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia yes, i tried it but it wont work...

Comment: Post the relevant code where you send the request from the client

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia it's spelled "rEgistration". . . .i didnt get it??

Comment: your System.out.println's. It's rEgistration and succesfuL (single L)

Comment: protected List<FileItem> initRequest(HttpServletRequest req) 
 {
  boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req);
     if(!isMultipart) throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
     DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
     factory.setSizeThreshold(THRESHOLD_SIZE);
     factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

Comment: ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
     upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
     upload.setSizeMax(REQUEST_SIZE);
     List<FileItem> formItems = null;
     try 
      {
      formItems = upload.parseRequest(req);
      } 
     catch (Exception e) 
      {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }

Comment: Anand, the code should be in the question, not in the comments: please edit it there. Also, this code doesn't seem to be setting the parameters you are trying to retrieve, therefore they are null?

Comment: public void init()
 {
  
  try
  {
   
   con = DbConnection.getConnection();
  }
  catch(Exception e1)
  {
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

Comment: ok thanks for your valuable reply

Comment: hello i got a problem why this code dosent work...

Comment: as soon as  fileItem = initRequest(req); it catches all the attribute and then name=req.getParameter("name"); now req dosent have a value to catch...... now my query is to do both the task simulteniously........